# Eclipse with DLTK plugins for tcl, has multiple "Run Configurations"

Tags: eclipse, configuration, eclipse-plugin, tcl, dltk

Since setting up Eclipse with the DLTK plugins for TCL (from a fresh install) I've noticed that every time I attempt to 'run' or 'debug' I'm prompted to choose a run configuration.  These are listed as 'Tcl Script' and 'Tcl Testing'.

The run configuration propery panel shows both 'types' of configuration, but has no facility to remove them (the types, not the configurations themselves).

Is there any way I can remove the 'Tcl Testing' config *type*? Or some other way to prevent it asking me which type I want to use *every* time I run/debug a project?

I've tried ensuring I have only a single configuration defined, but it still asks me which configuration *type* I'd like to launch.

Comment: +1 for the Q. No real idea, but is there some kind of preference you can set? (I'm a little loth to fire up Eclipse to try it out; my system uses memory for other things too…)

Comment: Doesn't appear to be, thanks Donal. I think I'll have to hack around and see what comes up.. though, chances are I'll break something else ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Setup a new Debug Configuration of whichever type you want.  Under the common tab check off the 'display in famorites menu' boxes.  Hit Apply, then Debug.  It should launch properly.

From then on, when you hit Debug (or at least F11, as I do) it will launch that debug config every time.  If you run something else, that config will be an option in the drop-down.